# Launch a click function one after another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, delay

I have different functions such as:

```
  function showpanel() {     
$( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a" ).addClass('crop-anim');
$('body').addClass('stepone')

}

 function showcolor() {     
    $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a" ).addClass('cropcolor')
  }

  function hidepanel() {     
    $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a" ).removeClass('crop-anim')
    // $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a" ).addClass('slideup')
    $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a img.crop" ).removeClass('hide')
    $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a .right-align" ).removeClass('before')
    $( ".top-buttons .col-md-4 a img.title" ).removeClass('before')
    // $( ".top-buttons" ).removeClass('before')
    // $( ".top-buttons" ).css('margin-top','0px')
  }
```

I'd like to trigger a specific function on click, which work fine:

```
  $("#body").click(function() {
showpanel()
 });
```

The above work perfectly.

But what above if I want to launch the function hidepanel() right after the function showpanel has finish ??

How can I achieve this ?

I tried the following for the above scenario:

```
  $("#body").click(function() {
showpanel()
hidepanel(2800)
});
```

like to add a delay of 2800 ms but no success . . .

Scenario 2 i'm trying to achieve;

At the end of the showpanel function, hidepanel function trigger straight after. then on click of the body div again, it will trigger the function showcolor.

How is this possible to do ? Any help / pointers will be super !!

THank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) certainly is what you're after.

```
$("#body").click(function() {
  showpanel();

  setTimeout(function(){
    hidepanel();
  },2800);
});
```

**EDIT**

To trigger different actions based on a "click sequence", you can use [`switch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
var clickCounter = 0;

$("#body").click(function() {

  // Increment clickCounter
  clickCounter++;

  switch (clickCounter){

    // First click
    case 1:
      showpanel();

      setTimeout(function(){
        hidepanel(2800)
      },2800);

      break;

    // Second click
    case 2:
      FirstOtherAction();

      break;

    // Third click
    case 3:
      secondOtherAction();

      break;

    // All subsequent clicks
    default:
      allOtherAction();

      break;

   }  // End switch

});  // End click handler
```

Comment: that is brilliant thank you.

What about if I want once the hidepanel function is finish, to trigger a new function on click of body ( knowing I had already click once on body before to trigger the first function ?)

Comment: You want to loop an animation?

Comment: not sur if it loops, but id like on first click of body trigger the function showpanel. when shopnale has finish. start the function hidepanel ( good with your wnaser).

THen, ont hidepanel function has finish, If i click again on body, to trigger a new function.

once this function will be finish, on click again of body, to trigger another function, etc, etc . 

Really appreciate your time !

Comment: Ha ok... So different actions based on a click sequence then.

Comment: exactly, yes. if you have any tips for it ?

Comment: Seems to work ! Thanks !

Just one thing; If I click during the animation the case 2 start. Is there any way to start the animaton on the second click only when the hidepanel has finish ????

Sorry to be so picky :)

Comment: You could use another variable to track this... So, on second click, in the case #2, add an if `panelHidden == true` to perform what you wish... If it isn't true, something else, like to decrease `clickCounter` by one...

Comment: Hi Louys, not sur how I can make this work .. .   would you mind to show an example ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I made you a quick [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LQyzpB?editors=1111) ;) If, like I think, that is about CSS animations, you may need the [`onanimationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend) event to turn the flag to true.